# Notification bar doesn't push down the header area of the page correctly

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, notifications

This is only in Gaming and meta.Gaming; I can't reproduce this on any other StackExchange site. This is on IE7.

First, the notification bar does not push the header downwards with the entire page as it does on other sites: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Huw9X.png

Second, clicking anything in the header (for example, the logo), brings the header down to its correct position: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcV4O.png

Third, this is probably just a side effect of whatever issue it is, but if you scroll down while closing the notification bar, it gets a little screwy:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZBSL.png

Comment: `This is on IE7`.  I think I found your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have notified our programming team about this, since some of the styling are done with JQuery. But FYI, CSS-wise, for older browsers such as IE6/IE7FF2 etc, I'm not aiming for pixel perfect, as long as they're not functionally broken.